# How to select Multiple CSV files based on date and load into table

Tags: ssis

i receive input files daily in a folder called INPUTFILES. These files have filename along with datetime.

My Package has been scheduled to run everyday. If i receive 2 files for the day, i need to fetch these 2 files and load into the table.

For example i had files in my files

test20120508_122334.csv
test20120608_122455.csv
test20120608_014455.csv

now i need to run files test20120608_122455.csv  test20120608_014455.csv for the same day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. I have taken one varibale which checks for whether a file exists for that particular Day.

If the file exists for a particular day then the value for the variable is assigned to 1.

For Each Loop Container has been taken, and placed the this file exists variable inside the container.

```
For Loop Properties  

EvalExpression ---- @fileexists==1.
```

if no file exists for that particular day, then the loop fails.